# Customise Author Page?

Tags: php, author-template

On my website I would enjoy to make it so that if a reader clicks an author or user's name it takes them to a page displaying their profile picture and bio. All users on my blog have the option to add a profile picture or bio before signing up. How could I make it so that it displays the information they submit when their username is clicked? I think to do this you have to edit the author.php file but I'm not sure where to go from there. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

BTW - I am currently trying to learn PHP so hopefully soon I won't be asking questions like this.

Comment: Take a look at what the Twenty Fourteen default theme for WordPress includes as they have a author.php file you may find useful https://github.com/braddalton/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/author.php

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this in your `author.php` file. Taken from the Codex.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">

<!-- This sets the $curauth variable -->

<?php
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
?>

<h2>About: <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></h2>
<dl>
    <dt>Website</dt>
    <dd><a href="<?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?>"><?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?></a></dd>
    <dt>Profile</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $curauth->user_description; ?></dd>
</dl>

<h2>Posts by <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?>:</h2>

<ul>
<!-- The Loop -->

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?></a>,
        <?php the_time('d M Y'); ?> in <?php the_category('&');?>
    </li>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- End Loop -->

</ul>
```

To get the profile photo you need to use the `get_avatar` function and use the users email as a parameter.

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $curauth->user_email ); ?>
```

More information on `get_avatar` here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar